# How to use $dates array and Factory together

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-factory

I have a factory with the below definition

```php
public function definition()
{
    $startDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y', $this->faker->year);
    $endDate = $startDate->addYear();

    return [
        'name' => $startDate->year,
        'start_date' => $startDate->format('Y-m-d'),
        'end_date' => $endDate->format('Y-m-d'),
    ];
}
```

So this generates an array like below

```
[
    'name' => 2020,
    'start_date' => '2020-01-30',
    'end_date' => '2021-01-30'
]
```

The above worked as expected until a requirement to return the `start_date` field and the `end_date` field arose. So in my model I added:

```php
protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'start_date', 'end_date'];
```

In my validators, I validate that the format is `Y-m-d`.

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|unique:academic_years',
        'start_date' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d|before_or_equal:end_date',
        'end_date' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d',
    ];
}
```

I also have the below test:

```
public function should_throw_error_if_date_format_is_invalid()
{
    Permission::factory()->state(['name' => 'create academic year'])->create();

    $user = User::factory()->create();
    $user->givePermissionTo('create academic year');

    $this->actingAs($user, 'api')->postJson('/api/academic-years', [
        'name' => $this->faker->year,
        'start_date' => '01-01-2019',
        'end_date' => '2019-01-01'
    ])->assertStatus(422);

    $this->actingAs($user, 'api')->postJson('/api/academic-years', [
        'name' => $this->faker->year,
        'end_date' => '01-01-2019',
        'start_date' => '2019-01-01'
    ])->assertStatus(422);
}
```

The test fails, but If I remove the `$dates` array, the test passes. On checking the object passed into the request I see a different date format `{"name":1995,"start_date":"1995-04-04T00:00:00.000000Z","end_date":"1995-04-04T00:00:00.000000Z"}` from the format provided in the `Factory`.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Faker` is returning a `DateTime-Object` which isn't representing a date-string like `mysql` likes it (`Y-m-d H:i:s`).

You should however be able to access the objects property `date` to get the correct string like this:

Try this

```
public function definition()
{
    $startDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y', $this->faker->year);
    $endDate = $startDate->addYear();
    
    return [
        'name' => $startDate->year,
        'start_date' => $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'end_date' => $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    ];
}
```

This should return a date like this `string '1995-04-04T00:00:00.000000Z'`

or

By default, timestamps are formatted as 'Y-m-d H:i:s'. If you need to customize the timestamp format, set the $dateFormat property on your model. This property determines how date attributes are stored in the database, as well as their format when the model is serialized to an array or JSON:

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The storage format of the model's date columns.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $dateFormat = 'U';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion unfortunately the requirement is to validate the string in the format 'Y-m-d' as I do not have control over the frontend.

Comment: The second approach looks promising. Just one question, how will I be able to separate different date formats?